# Dell Poweredge 2900 SAS Raid 1 Data Consistency Check Failure

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

We have at work a Powerdge with two SAS drivers in a RAID1 configuration, it's been like this since way before I started but today we started getting disk access errors on the console so I took a look. The Dell configuration tools show that the RAID is degraded, when I attempt to run the consistency check it fails immediately.

How I get the consistency check to run/how do I repair the data consistency?

Comment: Why are you sure you can?  Software usually won't fix a hardware fault.

Comment: I wasn't, that's why I asking. If it was a hardware fault a simple answer of 'it's most probably hardware, replace the discs' would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the server is under warranty just replace the drive. you can **never** be to careful when it comes to your data.

Don't want to risk losing your other drive cause then your just plain out of luck!

Comment: It's outside of warranty, I'll get some new drives ordered. Thanks for your answer.